# What does "My layers are thick" mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning, lyrics

In the song ["Fuel my Fire" by L7](https://genius.com/L7-fuel-my-fire-lyrics) it says:

> Yeah, my layers are thick
>
> And I got a bad attitude

What does "My layers are thick" mean in this context? Is it another way to say "I've got a thick skin"?

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it, the meaning is not totally clear.

My main guess is the same as yours: "thick skin".

However, even though less likely, it may refer to many / thick layers of clothes. A "gangster" may wear a protective layer of clothes - in the idea of bullet proof vests. Also, homeless people (sometimes) wear all clothes the have at the same time, regardless of the temperature outside.

Comment: This song is originally performed by a female singer. Would she refer to layers of clothes gangsts style?

Comment: The way I read and understood the song, it is irrelevant if a man or a woman sings.

Comment: It has been covered by The Prodigy, so it is indeed irrelevant. But I don't known if a woman would sing about her thick clothes.

Comment: It depends who is the woman in the song. On the other hand, I saw **men** at **straight** parties singing along with Barbara Streisand: "I am a **woman** in love..." :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it could mean that they are extremely confident, or closely allied to members of their own profession.

For example, they will meet their peers for a drink after a case is closed. Then they will discuss the pros and cons of the case, even if they were in opposition to each other in open court.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Your answer seems to be based on "my lawyers are thick." It is "my **layers** are thick." Did you misread the sentence at issue?